# How to Authenticate a desktop app with OAuth 2.0 and Procore API

Tags: .net, wpf, oauth-2.0

Im not very familiar with the whole OAuth 2.0 but I have been reading about it and also the procore API. Now I'm stuck and I need help with this:

Im creating a Desktop App to get a Authorization Token, I'm able to get the Authorization Token to show in the browser  [image]

I can also get it by using Post Man.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // client configuration
    const string clientID = "";
    const string clientSecret = "";
    const string authorizationEndpoint = "https://login-sandbox.procore.com/oauth/authorize";
    const string tokenEndpoint = "https://login-sandbox.procore.com/oauth/token";
   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Generates state and PKCE values.
        string state = randomDataBase64url(32);


        // Creates a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
        string redirectURI = string.Format("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");

        // Creates an HttpListener to listen for requests on that redirect URI.
        var http = new HttpListener();


        // Creates the OAuth 2.0 authorization request.
        string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}",authorizationEndpoint,System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),clientID);

        // Opens request in the browser.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest);

        // Waits for the OAuth authorization response.
       var context = await http.GetContextAsync();

        // Brings this app back to the foreground.
        this.Activate();

        // Sends an HTTP response to the browser.
        var response = context.Response;
        string responseString = string.Format("<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;url=https://google.com'></head><body>Please return to the app.</body></html>");
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        var responseOutput = response.OutputStream;
        Task responseTask = responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) => 
        {
            responseOutput.Close();
            http.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
        });

        // Checks for errors.
        if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("error") != null)
        {
            output(String.Format("OAuth authorization error: {0}.", context.Request.QueryString.Get("error")));
            return;
        }
        if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("code") == null
            || context.Request.QueryString.Get("state") == null)
        {
            output("Malformed authorization response. " + context.Request.QueryString);
            return;
        }

        // extracts the code
        var code = context.Request.QueryString.Get("code");
        var incoming_state = context.Request.QueryString.Get("state");

        // Compares the receieved state to the expected value, to ensure that
        // this app made the request which resulted in authorization.
        if (incoming_state != state)
        {
            output(String.Format("Received request with invalid state ({0})", incoming_state));
            return;
        }
        output("Authorization code: " + code);

        // Starts the code exchange at the Token Endpoint.
        performCodeExchange(code, redirectURI);
    }
```

When the request is open in the browser and I enter my credentials I get the token displayed on the browser window. When i get to the line "Waits for the OAth autorization response" I get this error:

[image]

I'll appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: You need to call http.Start(); before getting context. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-6.0#examples

Comment: I did, but it stays hanging. How can i capture the Authorization code before is shown in  the browser? I'am so confused.

Comment: Look at the working example from microsoft docs. You are creating redirectUri for authorization request, but your http listener does not listen on that one. You need to set Uri prefixes.